# SSRS Reports : 'ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace' property can't find in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I can't find the report property 'ConsumeContainerSpace' in Visual Studio 2010.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Actually, I didn't click in the right zone. There must be doing a left click not on the report but in the zone on the right of the report and then see the report property on right-below